# Problem with using updated values from config file in Codeigniter on autoloading

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use input form in admin dashboard for changing values in custom config file that is loaded in codeigniter over autoloading. I have issue that after submiting(saving), form  values are saved in config file but they are not updated in `$this->config->item`.

After sending form data to controller and successful saving in config file page is reloaded. Right(updated) values appear in input fields only after one more reload. If config file is loaded only in current controller (not over autoloading) it works ok, but it is needed in many controllers and models. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: use a database-based configuration. it is better than overwriting a configuration file array (which is what I am assuming you are doing as CodeIgniter `set` methods for `config` are only pervasive in that instance).

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know the data loaded in autoloader is loaded before controller execution. So if you change the data in a called controller it will always differ until reload.

I would recommend handling the data either in a database table or manage it manually in a file (outsource file operation in a library).